# Origin of notation "R with a stroke on the leg" for the square-root (℞)

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, notation

The following text from [Ars magna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_Magna_(Cardano_book)) (1545) by Girolamo Cardano is known as the inception of complex numbers: "imaginaberis ℞ m 15" (You will imagine the square root of  minus 15):

[image: Ars magna, complex numbers inception]

The "R" with the stroke on its leg could read as ℞ (Rx), an abbreviation for *radix*, or root in Latin. Was this notation frequent, and does it have a known origin?

Note: this appears on the page *Cap. XXXVII. De Regula fals. 287, Demonstratio* of this Latin version of [*Artis magnae sive de regulis algebraicis, liber unus*](http://www.filosofia.unimi.it/cardano/testi/operaomnia/vol_4_s_4.pdf).

[image: Artis magnae sive de regulis algebraicis, liber unus, Cap. XXXVII. De Regula fals. 287, Demonstratio]

Comment: Leo Corry, in his *Brief History of Numbers*, refers to ℞ as "Cardano's shorthand", citing [Gavagna 2012, page 7](http://web.math.unifi.it/archimede/note_storia/gavagna-complessi.pdf).  Corry continues by noting that Bombelli used the unadorned "R", e.g., "R.c" for cubed root.  This suggests that perhaps the use of ℞ in mathematics was introduced by Cardano himself.  The use of ℞ in medical prescriptions continues to this day and we know that medieval physicians used ℞ so perhaps (it's a stretch) Bombelli and others wished to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: Thank you for this source. I just read from Cadori (*A history of mathematical notations*) that the use of Rx as *radix* is also seen in Leonardo of Pisa (1170-1240) and Luca Pacioli (1447-1517). I will dig a bit  further.

Comment: Leonardo and Luca used ℞ ambiguously, for the unknown and the square root, the former use is older. For uses contemporaneous with Cardano, e.g. by Peletier, see [Printers and algebraists in mid-16th century France by Loget](https://www.philosophica.ugent.be/wp-content/uploads/fulltexts/87-3.pdf).

Comment: @Nick but  the medical "Rx"  is simply an abbreviation.  "Dx" for diagnosis and "Rx" for recommendation/ prescription.

Comment: Abbreviation for "take" (*recipe*) if I read it well